# ConversionPattern to log the hostname in JBossFuse / Apache Camel (ops4j)

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse, ops4j

Using JBoss Fuse / Apache Camel, writing to log file configured in `org.ops4j.pax.logging.properties`, I would like to log the host name.

```
log4j.appender.myapp.layout.ConversionPattern=${host} %d{ISO8601} %p %X{bundle.id} %c{1} %m%n
```

The part in the converstion pattern `${host}` doesn't work.

Is there a way I can get this? Is there something like `%X{host.name}`?

In the code I read about `HOSTNAMENONCANON` - perhaps can I access that?

The log framework is `OPS4j`, and whilst the patterns look similar to log4j, I am not sure if they work in the same way, or indeed if a way to log the host name via log4j would also work here (but it might be worth a try).

Thanks, VikingSteve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you can use `%X{hostname}` if you configure this via the `MDC` static method:

```
MDC.put("hostname", xyz);
```

I'm not sure if this is the best solution? It seems fine to me (?).